View selected cells in Excel row by row
2 or more continuous cells in a row are selected (highlighted) and I want to view the same selection in the next or previous row by moving selected cells view (NOT data or contents) up or down by row with a keyboard command.
With a single cell selected the arrow keys will move the view.
How do you do the same thing with multiple cells (in the same row AND connected) with a keyboard command?

Keep the same layout of cells selected, when moving over rows. Possibly by use of a special macro... I'd suggest selecting COLUMNS instead of cells (click column heading!)

Without macros, you can do that.
Select the area for which you want to move the selection. The active cell must be the first cell of that area. Press and hold the Shift key, and then press the arrow key (which direction you want to move), the Tab key, and then press the same arrow key again.

... all while you hold SHIFT? (LibreOffice: strange effects...)

Yes, tested in Excel only.

More possibilities here: https://www.excelcampus.com/keyboard-shortcuts/move-selected-range/
